# HIGHCHARTS GANTT / X labels not rendering, not rotating, not overlapping

Tags: highcharts

I have a chart with 3 X axes, the first show the year, the next line shows the Quarter (3 months) and the third by month, the expected behavior is similar to the following:
[image]

Now I do understand that because of the space, some of them disappear, but I tried to use allowOverlap and nothing happnes, rotate 90 or -90 and also nothing happens, and the worst of all is... when I zoom it shows correctly, but if I zoom out then zoom in other part of the chart, most of the months don't show, not because of lack of space, not sure why?, please take a look:
[image]
and when zooming out... (at the beginning it was showing just some months because of space, how did this get the space now?)
[image]
and when zooming back in...
[image]

please take a look at my code below:

```js
            xAxis: [

                {
                    tickInterval: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30,
                    labels: {
                        allowOverlap: true,
                        format: '{value:%b}',
                        style: {
                            fontSize: '8px'
                        },
                        rotate: 90,

                    },
                    units: [
                        [
                            'month',
                            [1]
                        ]
                    ]
                },

                {
                    currentDateIndicator: {
                        width: 1,
                        dashStyle: 'dash',
                        color: 'red', 
                        label: undefined,
                    },

                    tickInterval: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30,

                    units: [[
                        'month',
                        [3]
                    ],],

                    labels: {

                        align: "center",
                        allowOverlap: true,
                        formatter: function AxisLabelsFormatterCallbackFunction() {

                            var providedLocalDate = new Date(this.value);

                            var realDate = new Date(providedLocalDate.getTime() + (providedLocalDate.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000));

                            var month = realDate.getMonth();

                            var QuarterNumber;
                            var MonthInits = [];

                            if (month >= 0 && month <= 2) {
                                QuarterNumber = 1;
                                MonthInits[0] = 'J';
                                MonthInits[1] = 'F';
                                MonthInits[2] = 'M';
                            }
                            if (month >= 3 && month <= 5) {
                                QuarterNumber = 2;
                                MonthInits[0] = 'A';
                                MonthInits[1] = 'M';
                                MonthInits[2] = 'J';
                            }
                            if (month >= 6 && month <= 8) {
                                QuarterNumber = 3;
                                MonthInits[0] = 'J';
                                MonthInits[1] = 'A';
                                MonthInits[2] = 'S';
                            }
                            if (month >= 9 && month <= 11) {
                                QuarterNumber = 4;
                                MonthInits[0] = 'O';
                                MonthInits[1] = 'N';
                                MonthInits[2] = 'D';
                            }

                            return `<div style="font-size: x-small; font-family:arial;font-weight:bold; color:${((QuarterNumber == 1 | QuarterNumber == 3) ? "#B86B00;" : "#0068B5;")};">QTR ${QuarterNumber}</div>`;


                        },
                    },

                },
                {
                    tickInterval: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365, // Year
                    labels: {
                        format: '{value:%Y}',
                        style: {
                            fontSize: '15px'
                        }
                    },
                },
            ],
```

Comment: It's look like bug reported here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/15720, as a workaround you can also adjust the fontSize inside labels. [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/260L54e1/)

Comment: Thank you Sebastian, unfortunately I don't think a label 8px could be reduced even more... I did check the example but their workaround is not even working properly, showing years and years... not sure what they were trying to accomplish there...